# How to represent samples that can belong to multiple categories of a categorical feature

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, classification, feature-extraction

For example, say I have these data points:

```
feature: color                        class
---------------------------------------------
red, green                         A
yellow, orange                     B
blue, green, red                   A
yellow                             B
```

The categorical feature column would be [red, blue, green, yellow, orange], but each sample can belong to multiple categories (such as (red, green)).

One approach would be to represent each category (color) as it's own column, and then perform a binary encoding on top of that (1 or 0 for true or false).

Would this be the best approach in Tensorflow, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what's the final purpose of your problem? Is it to predict the colors present in an image or predict the class of an image to be 'A' or 'B', based on the colors?

Also, from the above examples, it seems like when you have red and green its 'A' and when you have yellow, its 'B'. I hope you have more contradicting examples to this.

Comment: The purpose of this classification problem is to determine the class (A or B) based on the features of an image. This was just a dummy example, I'm asking about how I should represent these features in Tensorflow. Thanks!

Comment: another usecase that ive seen before, would be texts categorised with various tags. Think blogs and news articles. They often have multiple tags which assist with organisation - as a very brief summary of the text. "Trump visits G7 leaders in Paris" might be #trump #paris #g7.  When I was looking at a similar problem I was searching for some way of doing a 'Multi-hot' feature column that could be used directly or embedded.  I eventually ended up using separate binary classifiers for each possible label, but that was not ideal. It stopped the model learning any relationships between tags.

Comment: better example would be Stackoverflow questions!